# javascript to call new HTMLpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem calling a HTML page via javascript. It might be simple, but I am just learning.Hope some can help.

```
<label value="Login" id="lbl1" ontouchstart="mouseDown1()" ontouchend="mouseUp1()">Login</label>
```

javascript

```
function mouseUp1() {
    var styles = {
        "background": "url(img/b_long_off.png)",
        "background-size": "100% 100%",
        "height": "36px",
        "width": "93%",
        "position": "absolute",
        "text-align": "center",
        "padding-top": "18px",
        "left": "3.5%",
        "top": "208px",    
        "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
        "font-size": "16px",
        "color": "white"
    };
    $("#lbl1").css(styles); $.mobile.changePage("register.html");
}
```

I am calling the label by ID when the mouse is up. The page gets loaded, but the styles are not applied. I am using jquery and jQuery mobile with phonegap. Didn't use any of the methods provided by jQuery/phonegap,like, mobileinit or onready or etc..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hvEs2/ seems to be working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found when using jQuery mobile that if you declare the CSS/JS outside of your `<div data-role="page">` node that it won't load up new styles or scripts. This is because of the way jQuery mobile loads up new content. It does it asynchronously within the `<div data-role="page">` element.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I modified and the page is now loading with the styles. Is it possible to separate the HTML, CSS and JS??

Comment: Hi, when you say separate them out, do you mean have them all in their individual files? Also, feel free to upvote and mark this answer as correct =p.

Comment: Yes, I need to have them in their respective files and use them from there.

Comment: Ok well put them all in their own separate files and add in tags to your HTML within the body that reference them e.g.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Pages/IndexMobile.js"></script>`